# Implode array list elements with indexing

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array list that I wish to implode as I want to display each array with indexing to target that element. I'm trying but it is not displaying correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

/*
var_dump($names); // below
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "David Kaul"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "Julius Kaul"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "Robert Kaul"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "Juohn Kaul"
} */

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i+=1) {
    echo '<li class="item-' . $i . '">' . implode('</li><li class="item-'.$i.'">', $names) . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why does your loop count to 10 when there are only 4 names in `$names`?

Comment: There may be 5 or 7 or up to 10 in some cases

Comment: Instead of hardcode 10 you can use count($names)

Comment: Why not use `foreach`?

Comment: How is it "not displaying correctly"?

Comment: What's the point of individual class identifiers for the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple `foreach` over the `$names` array:

```
$names = array("David Kaul","Julius Kaul","Robert Kaul","Juohn Kaul");
foreach ($names as $i => $name) {
    echo '<li class="item-' . $i . '">' . $name. '</li>' . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<li class="item-0">David Kaul</li>
<li class="item-1">Julius Kaul</li>
<li class="item-2">Robert Kaul</li>
<li class="item-3">Juohn Kaul</li>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gUWlb)